# why we need to to identify the external markers in marker-controlled watershed segmentaion?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

why we need to to identify the external markers in marker-controlled watershed segmentaion?
why it is not enough to identify internal markers of the objects of interest?

please help, i'm confused
thanks

Comment: From your question, it appears you're trying to script some existing watershed segmentation tool or algorithm, probably running in some GIS environment.  This seems more like a question about the specific algorithm you're using, rather than a programming question.

Comment: my question is about this: http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html

Answer (score 1):

Using mahotas, with a marker for the background, I get weird things like [that](http://dip4fish.blogspot.com/2011/01/test-images-for-geodesic-region-growing.html)